# Pessoal como percorrer um array com múltiplas requisições?

Tags: php

Estou recebendo este objeto via API e precisaria percorrer cada uma dessas paginas, lembrando que cada pagina é uma requisição. Aqui nessa demostração estou na pagina 1 cada pagina me traz 50 registros e o retorno me mostra que existem 39 paginas.. como eu percorro essas 39 paginas fazendo uma requisição a cada pagina? Desde fico muito agradecido pela ajuda de todos.

```
Array
(
[retorno] => Array
    (
        [status_processamento] => 3
        [status] => OK
        [pagina] => 1
        [numero_paginas] => 39
        [contas] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [conta] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 504024714
                                [nome_cliente] => IRINEU DOMINGOS ANTUNES
                                [historico] => CONTAS A PAGAR - (Cliente sistema antigo - incluso no SCPC)
                                [numero_banco] => 
                                [numero_doc] => 000022554
                                [serie_doc] => 0
                                [data_vencimento] => 10/12/2014
                                [situacao] => aberto
                                [data_emissao] => 28/11/2017
                                [valor] => 392.66
                                [saldo] => 392.66
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [conta] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 503982261
                                [nome_cliente] => MARCUS VINICIUS DE OLIVEIRA CUNHA
                                [historico] => Ref. Venda otica self care Elisama
                                [numero_banco] => 
                                [numero_doc] => 000270860
                                [serie_doc] => 0
                                [data_vencimento] => 27/02/2015
                                [situacao] => aberto
                                [data_emissao] => 28/11/2017
                                [valor] => 444.00
                                [saldo] => 444.00
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [conta] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 503885902
                                [nome_cliente] => LUIZ CARLOS MIRANDA
                                [historico] => CONTAS A RECEBER - PEDIDO 5912 - LUIZ CARLOS MIRANDA - Parcela (1/8)
                                [numero_banco] => 
                                [numero_doc] => 000005912
                                [serie_doc] => 0
                                [data_vencimento] => 14/01/2016
                                [situacao] => aberto
                                [data_emissao] => 27/11/2017
                                [valor] => 125.00
                                [saldo] => 125.00
                            )

                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [conta] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 503885904
                                [nome_cliente] => LUIZ CARLOS MIRANDA
                                [historico] => CONTAS A RECEBER - PEDIDO 5912 - LUIZ CARLOS MIRANDA - Parcela (2/8)
                                [numero_banco] => 
                                [numero_doc] => 000021248
                                [serie_doc] => 0
                                [data_vencimento] => 13/02/2016
                                [situacao] => aberto
                                [data_emissao] => 27/11/2017
                                [valor] => 125.00
                                [saldo] => 125.00
                            )

                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [conta] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 503991231
                                [nome_cliente] => WELLIGTON RODRIGO RIBEIRO DA SILVA
                                [historico] => CONTAS A RECEBER - PEDIDO 1452 - WELLIGTON RODRIGO RIBEIRO DA SILVA - Parcela (1/10)
                                [numero_banco] => 
                                [numero_doc] => 000001452
                                [serie_doc] => 0
                                [data_vencimento] => 13/02/2016
                                [situacao] => aberto
                                [data_emissao] => 28/11/2017
                                [valor] => 30.00
                                [saldo] => 30.00
                            )

                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute um foreach a cada nível do array.

```
foreach($retornoDaAPI['retorno'] as $key => $value){
    foreach($value['contas'] as $key2 => $value2){
       //e assim sucessivamente
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta Marcos Fabre.
Exemplo quando faço uma requisição eu tenho um retorno com 50 registrários por  pagina até sí bacana consigo percorrer tranquilo o array.
só api me manda separado todos os registros num total de 39 paginas.
ou seja são 39 requisições que terei de fazer... mas como fazer? lembrando que informo um parametro na url informando qual pagina quero obter  ex &pagina=5,  na url da requisição. mas pretendo saber se existe uma foma de trazer percorrer todas essas paginas numa unica chamada a api.